# ChartJS is not rendered

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I am Web Forms developer and not really good with JavaScript

Now I need to add charts in my project, and my customer chose these [ChartJS](http://chartjs.devexpress.com)

Yes, they look extremely good, their [demo](http://demos.devexpress.com/DXTREME/Visualization/#index) is quite beautiful and shows lots of useful features, but the code just does not work for me!

Based on code snippets on their site, I have created a div:

```
<div id="chartContainer"/>
```

Then I copied code from their demo center:

```
$("#chartContainer").dxChart({
    dataSource: [
        {day: "Monday", oranges: 3},
        {day: "Tuesday", oranges: 2},
        {day: "Wednesday", oranges: 3},
        {day: "Thursday", oranges: 4},
        {day: "Friday", oranges: 6},
        {day: "Saturday", oranges: 11},
        {day: "Sunday", oranges: 4} ],

    series: {
        argumentField: "day",
        valueField: "oranges",
        name: "My oranges",
        type: "bar",
        color: "orange"
    }
});
```

No result.
Tried to search here, but found only mentions of some another ChartJS... I think it is not ChartJS what I use...

Can anyone please help me to make it working?

Comment: Are you using this snippet without loading the library?

Comment: Thanks for asking, but I added reference to the library

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just go to ChartJS and hit the big orange download-button. The zip contains code exampels you need. The exampels on the ChartJS page have only the parts significant for demontration.

Comment: Thank you mrak, I have downloaded this zip, but the code in demo is exactly the same

Comment: I found my mistake - it appears I had to set the size of div:

    <div id="chartContainer" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"/>

I copied this from demo and it works fine!

Comment: Thanks for this. Checked out the samples on github and it worked for me.

Comment: Use <canvas> instead of <div>.