# Mozilla addon sdk chartjs not rendering

Tags: charts, sdk, firefox-addon

I've been attempting to render a ChartJS graph on pages a user loads with a Firefox add-on. I'm using the add-on SDK to insert a PageMod to every page:

```
pageMod.PageMod({
    include: "*",
    contentScriptFile: [data.url("jquery.js"), 
    data.url("Chart.js"), 
    data.url("onPageLoad.js")]
});
```

In my onPageLoad.js, I insert an HTML5 canvas element using jQuery, and then try to draw my graph on it:

```
var chartData = [{value:100,color:'#4C86B9',highlight:'#508CC2',label:'Blue Team'},{value:150,color:'#B9525C',highlight:'#C25660',label:'Red Team'}];

$(document).ready(function() {
    var ctx = document.getElementById("chart-area").getContext("2d");
    var myPieChart = new Chart(ctx).Pie(chartData, {responsive:true});
});
```

This only causes the canvas to expand in area (I can see its parent *div* element expanding), but no graph is rendered. Thus, I know that the libraries are indeed being loaded. The closest question I could find on SO is [ChartJS is not rendered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17019338/chartjs-is-not-rendered), but this is actually a completely different problem. I can trivially draw a rectangle to my canvas:

```
ctx.fillRect(10,20,200,100);
```

So if it's not a problem with the canvas itself, why is this ChartJS graph not rendering?

Comment: Have you checked if your `ready` function is called?

Comment: I do know that the ready function is called because I can draw a rectangle to the canvas for testing purposes, and I can even verify through console.log that the chartData is set properly. The canvas appears to resize to my desired chart size, but no actual graph is rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Are the jquery./js, chart.js and onpageload.js files located in your data folder? If that isnt the problem, then the problem may be cross domain thing, so youll have to get around by setting content script policies: [How to add Content Security Policy to Firefox extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19264831/how-to-add-content-security-policy-to-firefox-extension)

Comment: Sorry I didn't specify -- all my javascript files are indeed in my data folder and I know they are being loaded just fine. Since the chart.js is in the data folder (that is, I'm loading it locally), it shouldn't need a cross domain policy.

Comment: I was thinking maybe those files depended on some files out there on the net so it may have needed it. So no dependencies on any cloud files?

Comment: According to the ChartJS documentation here, http://www.chartjs.org/docs/, you only need to include the chart.js file, not any other dependency such as jQuery. I even searched through the chart.js source code and found no signs of imports, so I don't think it has any dependencies.